# Appending an element created as an object property

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I have a script which appends a newly-created div to the body element onload. I need to keep a reference to that div throughout the application, so I store it in my main global object.

```
var oMyObj = {};

window.onload = function () {
    oMyObj.eDiv = document.createElement("div");
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(oMyObj.eDiv);
};
```

Nothing particularly ground-breaking, I'm sure you'll agree. Anyway, it worked absolutely fine until I started testing in IE9. All of a sudden I get an error message saying "オブジェクトの呼び出しが無効です" (I'm currently working in Japan), which sort of translates to "the object call was null/invalid". Not sure what the precise English version of the error message is.

Anyway, I searched and found (http://d.hatena.ne.jp/wang-zhi/20110503/1304361114 - sorry, also in Japanese) that it was due to the <strike>RealPlayer</strike> DivX plugin. After disabling the plugin, it worked fine. It also works fine if I use a meta tag to force IE9 to run as IE7. So it is not a major problem. But I would like to know if there is a "correct" way to do what I am trying to do so that it will work in IE9 as IE9. I can only assume that what I am doing now is not what I'm supposed to be doing.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that.

Comment: Could it be that oMyObj.eDiv is referenced before onload? What is the value of oMyObj when the error occurs? In other words: Is it oMyObj or oMyObj.eDiv that is null?

Comment: Are the results the same if you change `var oMyObj` and `oMyObj` to `window.oMyObj`? That way you will make sure it's actually global.

Comment: I don't see any obvious problem. Are you sure the code you are showing are the offending lines? Try commenting them out and see if you still the problem.

Comment: According to the debugger, the element is created normally and added normally. It is working perfectly in that sense, as far as I can see. I can't imagine how `oMyObj.eDiv` could be referenced before onload; the super-simplified code I posted is all I am using to test the problem at the moment. Changing it to `window.oMyObj` did nothing.

Comment: Okay, well as I said, I am certain the problem is a result of the plugin. Since nobody seems to think the technique I am using is incorrect, I guess I will just have to stick with serving the page as IE7 via meta tags. At least I know it wasn't my coding that was the problem. Thanks anyway, guys.

Comment: Check the return of `document.getElementsByTagName("body")` or even `document`. Maybe you got a typo in the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, well I have confirmation that it was the DivX (not RealPlayer; no idea why I mixed them up) Plugin causing the problem. The plugin overwrites some of the core DOM functionality, including appendChild, which seems insane to me, but whatever. DivX [acknowledged](http://labs.divx.com/node/16824) the bug and are apparently going to fix it in the next update. Yay, I guess.